# revealjs not adjusting properly inside twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reveal.js

I am trying to add [revealjs](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) inside [twitter bootstrap,](http://getbootstrap.com) it seems to be appearing but not properly. Please note it is only the appearance that is not right, it seems to jump from slide to slide just fine.

There are two problems with it

1. The size of revealjs slides is really small, i have not changed anything in css that could have caused this but I did find out that the slides seem to be appearing fine if i dont integrate them with bootstrap.
2. The background of revealjs fills the whole screen instead of the div where slides/sections are being placed.

This is what my screen looks like
[image]

This is what my page html looks like with twitter bootstrap and revealjs slide sections inside class `col-lg-8`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Multi Form</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/bootstrap-3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/design.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/css/reveal.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/css/theme/default.css" id="theme">

    <!-- For syntax highlighting -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/lib/css/zenburn.css">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap-3.1.1/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- If the query includes 'print-pdf', include the PDF print sheet -->
    <script>
        if (window.location.search.match(/print-pdf/gi)) {
            var link = document.createElement('link');
            link.rel = 'stylesheet';
            link.type = 'text/css';
            link.href = 'css/print/pdf.css';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
        }
    </script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <!--<script src="assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/lib/js/html5shiv.js"></script>-->
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Form Generator</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container main-wrapper">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <h3>This is a test and test is something that should be taken seriusly</h3>

            <div class="reveal">

                <!-- Any section element inside of this container is displayed as a slide -->
                <div class="slides">
                    <section>
                        <h1>Reveal.js</h1>

                        <h3>HTML Presentations Made Easy</h3>

                        <p>
                            <small>Created by <a href="http://hakim.se">Hakim El Hattab</a> / <a
                                    href="http://twitter.com/hakimel">@hakimel</a></small>
                        </p>
                    </section>


                    <section>
                        <h2>Slides</h2>

                        <p>
                            Not a coder? No problem. There's a fully-featured visual editor for authoring these, try it
                            out at <a
                                href="http://slid.es" target="_blank">http://slid.es</a>.
                        </p>
                    </section>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<script src="assets/bootstrap-3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/js/reveal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

    // Full list of configuration options available here:
    // https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
    Reveal.initialize({
        controls: true,
        progress: true,
        history: true,
        center: true,

        theme: Reveal.getQueryHash().theme, // available themes are in /css/theme
        transition: Reveal.getQueryHash().transition || 'default', // default/cube/page/concave/zoom/linear/fade/none

        // Parallax scrolling
        //parallaxBackgroundImage: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/hakim-static/reveal-js/reveal-parallax-1.jpg',
        //parallaxBackgroundSize: '2100px 900px',

        // Optional libraries used to extend on reveal.js
        dependencies: [
            { src: 'assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function () {
                return !document.body.classList;
            } },
            { src: 'assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function () {
                return !!document.querySelector('[data-markdown]');
            } },
            { src: 'assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function () {
                return !!document.querySelector('[data-markdown]');
            } },
            { src: 'assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/plugin/highlight/highlight.js', async: true, callback: function () {
                hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
            } },
            { src: 'assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true, condition: function () {
                return !!document.body.classList;
            } },
            { src: 'assets/reveal.js-2.6.2/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true, condition: function () {
                return !!document.body.classList;
            } }
        ]
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I will really appreciate any assistance in this

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
It turned out to be a problem when reveal calculates the wrapper height. 
Try to change the availableHeight variable in the function `layout()` in reveal.js.

Replace `availableHeight = dom.wrapper.offsetHeight;`

With `availableHeight = Math.max(dom.wrapper.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);`

Comment: Do you have an example? Where would you put this code?